# Closed solution of $\int\frac{x^n}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^{k}}{k!}}dx$

Tags: integration, summation

Is there a closed solution to

$$A(n,x) =\int\frac{x^n}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^{k}}{k!}}dx?$$

I was thinking of looking at the roots of the denominator to try split it into partial fractions but the I couldn't find any general method. Just dividing the polynomials doesn't seem to do much and there doesn't seem to me to be any obvious substitution/by parts method. Perhaps I'm missing something right under my nose?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: hey @Myridium, I was thinking of looking at the roots of the denominator to try split it into partial fractions but the I couldn't find any general method. Just dividing the polynomials doesn't seem to do much and there doesn't seem to me to be any obvious substitution/by parts method. Perhaps I'm missing something right under my nose? This is not a homework question I promise :P

Comment: @JonathanKeogh - [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Special_values) you can find the summation expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma Function. After replacing the sum with this expression, I would try integration by parts. Perhaps start with $n \rightarrow \infty$ because in that case the sum has a very nice answer... (hint: look at power series of $e^x$) I don't think you're going to find a closed form solution that doesn't include incomplete Gamma functions.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus - considering that *Mathematica* gives the closed form solution $-n! \log \left( \Gamma(1+n,x) \right)$, I think the problem is probably not intractable. Although it is debatable whether incomplete Gamma functions count as closed form.

Comment: I've reported this chain to the mods because this is off topic and very aggressive for MSE.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I've deleted the comments people thought rude, and the comments associated that did not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @JonathanKeogh: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: @robjohn you da bomb. Thanks for handling this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The finite sum appearing in the denominator of the integral turns out to be what is known as the [exponential sum function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html) $\exp_n (x)$. It can be expressed in terms of the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Upper_incomplete_Gamma_function) $\Gamma (a,x)$ as follows:
$$\exp_n (x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} =  \frac{e^x \Gamma (n + 1, x)}{\Gamma (n + 1)}.$$

Thus your indefinite integral reduces down to 
$$\int \frac{x^n}{\exp_n (x)} \, dx = n! \int \frac{e^{-x} x^n}{\Gamma (n + 1, x)} \, dx.$$

If we note that
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left (\Gamma (n + 1,x) \right ) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_x^\infty e^{-t} t^n \, dx = -e^{-x} x^n,$$
then we have
$$\int \frac{x^n}{\exp_n (x)} \, dx = -n! \ln[\Gamma(n + 1,x)] + C.$$

---

**Update**

We can write the final answer in a more manageable form involving the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Lower_incomplete_Gamma_function) $\gamma(a,x)$ where
$$\gamma (a,x) = \int_0^x e^{-t} t^{a - 1} \, dt,$$
rather than in terms of $\Gamma (a, x)$ which is improper.

Since $\gamma(a, x) + \Gamma (a, x) = \Gamma (a)$ where $\Gamma (a)$ is the normal gamma function, or in our case
$$\gamma (n + 1,x) + \Gamma (n + 1, x) = \Gamma (n + 1),$$
as the term $\Gamma (n + 1)$ is constant (independent of $x$) we have
$$\int \frac{x^n}{\exp_n (x)} \, dx = n! \cdot \ln[\gamma(n + 1,x)] + C.$$

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, the *incomplete Gamma functions* exist which can replace your summation term. They are defined as solutions to integrals, so whether this is "closed form" is debatable.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{e^x}{n!} \cdot\Gamma(1+n,x)$$
From which your integral becomes
$$A(n,x)=n! \cdot\int \frac{\frac{x^n}{e^x}}{\Gamma(1+n,x)}\, \mathrm d x$$

It turns out that this integral is solvable. First, let's look at the derivative of $\Gamma(1+n,x)$:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\left(\Gamma(1+n,x)\right) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left(\int_x^\infty t^{n} e^{-t}\, \mathrm d t\right) = -x^{n}e^{-x}$$

Well then, the factor on top of the $\Gamma$ denominator in our integral is equal to the $\Gamma$ function's derivative! So we have an integral of the form
$$\int - \frac{f'(x)} {f(x)}$$
whose solution is
$$-\log(f(x)) + C$$
and so our final answer is
$$A(n,x)=-n! \cdot \log \Big( \Gamma(1+n,x)\Big)$$
with the constant of integration, of course.